# "CXXABI_1.3.8 not found" Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: dependencies, ppa, 19.04, gcc, matlab

I'm having an issue with a dependencie of the MatLab runtime, it say that the `libstdc++.so.6` need `CXXABI_1.3.8`.

I've seen some post that propose ton install an old version of GCC by adding a PPA, the probleme is that this PPA isn't avaible for the 19.04 version of ubuntu. Do you know any solution to get this dependencie working ?

Comment: 19.04 / g++-8. ..... `objdump -x /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI_1.3.8` ... The reply is `37 0x00 0x0bafd178 CXXABI_1.3.8` .. `CXXABI_1.3.8` .... ?May be MatLab cannot search/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ ?

Comment: MatLab is not taking the `libstdc++.so.6` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` but in `/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/sys/os/glnxa64/`. Maybe I can tell MatLab to get the right `libstdc++`.

Comment: Please try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [other command]` . ... I.e. this will set /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu first in the search. Should work. Unless MatLab is hard coded to search only "/usr/local/MATLAB.... ... "

Comment: Work just fine. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 19.04, with g++-8

```
objdump -x /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI_1.3.8 
37 0x00 0x0bafd178 CXXABI_1.3.8 
        CXXABI_1.3.8
```

> Ref. MatLAB search:
>   /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/sys/os/glnxa64/

Please do :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [other command]
```

I.e. this will set `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` first in the search path.